# Is there auto increment over the full database (not each table!) in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Is there a proper native non-workaround auto increment possiblity for ALL tables together in mySQL ? I mean, not just auto inc per table, i mean ONE number counting up for EACH new row in the database ?

I have seen this on a professional oracle (?) set up. The main advantage is that you have unique id for ALL rows/elements in ALL tables, not just PER TABLE.

Comment: If you want to guarantee uniqueness, you could use MySQL's [`UUID_SHORT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short) function.

Comment: MySQL does not have sequences (as most other DBMS do). You need to roll your own solution.

Comment: I don't know of a native way. But maybe you could write an insert trigger that searches all tables for the highest index and return that value. At least in theory, honestly I'm not sure if that is possible in MySQL.

Comment: @acme That would be a tragic waste of CPU. If you just need overall uniqueness stick with UUIDs. They are of course large 128bit values so if you want to use smaller integers (BIGINT is 64bit) then use the sequence table i described.

Comment: @eggyal What size does a SHORT UUID occupy?

Comment: @MihaiStancu: The link in my comment to the definition of `UUID_SHORT()` states that the function returns "*a 64-bit unsigned integer*".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL can be setup like this with a `CREATE SEQUENCE seq_name` and using `nextval(seq_name)` on every insert.

MySQL does not have native support for this, you can simulate the behavior of a PostgreSQL SEQUENCE by creating a table with only one column and an `AUTO_INCREMENT` on that column.

You always insert into that table first read the `LAST_INSERT_ID` of that table to get the id you need to insert into your table. It would be transaction safe so not duplicates would ever be generated.

Another way to achieve this is to create a table with one column no `AUTO_INCREMENT` and only one row holding the current max value.

Every time you need to increment you execute `UPDATE seq_table SET seq_column = seq_colum+1;` an increment update is in itself atomic but you need to also read the value afterwards which makes two statements and they are not atomic together unless you set a transaction around them and an appropriate isolation level. This approach saves space but also generates locking queries.

Multiple threads trying to `INSERT` will have to wait for others to update the `seq_table` before being able to update it themselves and read the new value.

Also you'd have to wrap the `UPDATE` and the `SELECT` on `seq_table` in a transaction with an appropriate `ISOLATION LEVEL` to avoid reading the value that some other thread incremented after you incremented it.

This means that `INSERTS` become a transactional issue but normally they aren't, so i wouldn't recommend the second approach.

Comment: To get rid of the multiple rows in the first approach, we can first delete all rows and then do the insert.